# Tikz makes Overleaf unable to compile

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf

I am trying to use tikz to make a field tower. I have `\usepackage{tikz}`at the top, and when I comment out my tikz section, the file compiles with no problem. The section using tikz looks like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (Q1) at (0,0) {$\mathbb{Q}$};
\node (Q2) at (2,2) {$\mathbb{Q}\Big[\sqrt{7}\Big]$};
\node (Q3) at (0,4) {$\mathbb{Q}\Big[\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{7}\Big]$};
\node (Q4) at (-2,2) {$\mathbb{Q}\Big[\sqrt{3}\Big]$};

\draw (Q1)--(Q2)
\draw (Q1)--(Q4)
\draw (Q3)--(Q2)
\draw (Q3)--(Q4)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The error I am getting is "Sorry, your compile took too long to run and timed out." I know that usually means a fatal error, but the rest of my document compiles totally fine and I am not sure what is wrong with my tikz. I am using Overleaf and have never really had this problem before.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You need to add a semicolon `;` after every `\draw` (as well as after every `\fill`, `\node` and similar) macro in a Ti*k*Z environment. So, in your code, you need to write `\draw (Q1)--(Q2);` etc.

Comment: Lines between nodes you can write as `\draw (Q1)--(Q2)-- (Q3)--(Q4) -- (Q1);`

Comment: The reason for the timeout is that nested `\draw` (or node, fill, etc) commands create infinite loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- In Overleaf you can compile `tikzpicture`s without any problems
- but your picture code is erroneous. Each command in code had to be terminated with `;` as mentioned @Jasper Habich  in his comment.
  -Your code you ba srite also on the following way:

```
\documentclass[margin=3.141592,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (Q1) at (0,0)     {$\mathbb{Q}$};
\node (Q2) at (2,2)     {$\mathbb{Q}\Big[\sqrt{7}\Big]$};
\node (Q3) at (0,4)     {$\mathbb{Q}\Big[\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{7}\Big]$};
\node (Q4) at (-2,2)    {$\mathbb{Q}\Big[\sqrt{3}\Big]$};

\draw (Q1)--(Q2)-- (Q3)--(Q4) -- (Q1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same if you compile above MWE with local LaTeX installation or use Overleaf service:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using (off-topic) `tikz-cd` package you will have the same effect.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2cm, arrows=dash]
  &&   \mathbb{Q}\Big[\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{7}\Big] &  \\
   & \mathbb{Q}\Big[\sqrt{3}\Big] \arrow[ur] &&  \mathbb{Q}\Big[\sqrt{7}\Big] \arrow[ul] & \\
  &&   \arrow[ul] \mathbb{Q} \arrow[ur]  
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]